# Recursive Sequence "3, 5, -2, 7, -9, 16, -25, 41"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I start in solving this recursive sequence?  Thanks!

Sequence: 3, 5, -2, 7, -9, 16, -25, 41, ...

Comment: @Jay: I think you need to review the definition of "recursive sequence".  There is as yet no recursive anything in your question.

Comment: $a(1)=3, a(2)=5, a(n+2)=a(n)-a(n+1)$

Comment: @user3123 "How would I **start** in solving this recursive sequence?"

Comment: @milcak I guess there is no universal approach. With your answer you are doing the same thing as me, giving a spoiler to the solution but not provide how to generally solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @user3123 First of all, whatever "giving a spoiler to the solution" means to you, it is not the same as **giving the solution.** Following my anwser, maybe it could take him 10 seconds or 5 minutes to reach the solution. And I don't care. From your comment, he can toss the book he was reading away and do something else - without thought. And I tried to provide within my anwser how to generally solve such problems, and I'm sure it will be more helpful then what you attempted.

Comment: @user3123 well, at least you waited 10 hours. props.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to denote the problem using a matrix-formulation, with a guessed linear recursion involving for instance three elements:
$$ \begin{array} {rrrrrr}
& & & & x_1 & \\
& & & & x_2 & \\
& & & & x_3 & \\
--&--&--&-&-- \\
3&5&-2& &7\\
5&-2&7&=&-9 \\
-2&7&-9& &16\\

\end{array} $$

where the left matrix is **P**, the vector **X** contains the unknowns $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and the right vector is **Q**, with the obvious insertions. We ask: is the following matrix-equation solvable:
$$ P * X = Q $$ $$ X = P^{-1} * Q $$
thus first we check, whether **P** is invertible. Maybe we need only a *2x2*-matrix **P** or possibly we need higher dimension, if the the result is not correct for the following members of the given sequence. 
In our example we come along with a *2x2* matrix **P**

$$ \begin{array}{} P=\begin{pmatrix} 3&5 \\\ 5&-2 \end{pmatrix} & & 
P^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}  2/31 & 5/31 \\\ 5/31 & -3/31  \end{pmatrix} \end{array}$$

and get $X = (1,-1)$ so that $$a(k+2)=x_1 a(k)+x_2 a(k+1) = 1 a(k) - 1 a(k+1)$$

Comment: +1 this is a nice approach, especially when it gets more complicated.

Comment: @milcak:Thanks! One could smooth it using gaussian elimination on **P** and **Q**. Then the maximal allowed size for **P** (and its inverse) appears directly and we need not "try" to get the correct size (we get the rank of **P** directly)

Answer (score 1):

How does:

- $-2$ relate to $3$ and $5$?
- $7$ relate to $5$ and $-2$?
- $-9$ relate to $-2$ and $7$?

etc. If we write $f_i$ to be the $i$-th term in your sequence, these questions are just asking you: *How can you express $f_n$ in terms of $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$?*

Note that you may always define the first few numbers in a recursion by hand.

(Of course this is not some general strategy, but if you have such a problem, the desired formula won't be something *too* complicated - here I just *guessed* it would involve the two previous terms somehow, but again in general, that's probably the first thing you should try.)